# Cannot use the pyttsx3 python module

Tags: python, python-import, traceback

I was trying to use the python pyttsx3 module to say: "Hi World" , but the program crashed from the beginning onwards.

While trying to run the pyttsx3 programs , returns the following error

[image: The primary error says : cannot import SpeechLib from comtypes.gen]

Given Below is the program :

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("Hi World")
engine.runAndWait()
```

**I have installed all the dependencies required for the pyttsx3, but still, it doesn't work?
What should I do ?**

[image: Proof for "I have all the dependencies installed"]

[image: comtypes.gen folder in my pc]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: What python version are you running? How did you install pyttsx3 step-by-step?

Comment: Im using python 3 (using the conda environment)        installed the pyttsx3 using the following code : "python -m pip install pyttsx3"

Comment: This error: `https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=typeerror+item+1+in+_argtypes_+passes+a+union+by+value+which+is+unsupported&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8` seems to indicate that it's an issue with the version of python you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[follow the link and type as it is from the image, hope it helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6smvd.png)